# Can't delete node because of node_auto_index

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm trying to delete a node from the graph, but I receive this exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: read only index
    at org.neo4j.kernel.AbstractAutoIndexerImpl$ReadOnlyIndexToIndexAdapter.readOnlyIndex(AbstractAutoIndexerImpl.java:253) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.AbstractAutoIndexerImpl$ReadOnlyIndexToIndexAdapter.remove(AbstractAutoIndexerImpl.java:283) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.DelegatingGraphDatabase.removeFromIndexes(DelegatingGraphDatabase.java:107) ~[spring-data-neo4j-2.3.0.RC1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.DelegatingGraphDatabase.remove(DelegatingGraphDatabase.java:246) ~[spring-data-neo4j-2.3.0.RC1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.EntityRemover.removeNode(EntityRemover.java:53) ~[spring-data-neo4j-2.3.0.RC1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.EntityRemover.removeNodeEntity(EntityRemover.java:45) ~[spring-data-neo4j-2.3.0.RC1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.EntityRemover.remove(EntityRemover.java:85) ~[spring-data-neo4j-2.3.0.RC1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.delete(Neo4jTemplate.java:222) ~[spring-data-neo4j-2.3.0.RC1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.AbstractGraphRepository.delete(AbstractGraphRepository.java:328) ~[spring-data-neo4j-2.3.0.RC1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.AbstractGraphRepository.delete(AbstractGraphRepository.java:333) ~[spring-data-neo4j-2.3.0.RC1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
```

After some debugging, I found out that this happens during the attempt to delete the node from the `node_auto_index`.

The graph has been set up with a auto-indices on nodes and relationships, which have been created upon starting up the graph with the neo4j standalone-server (version 1.9.M03). This is about the `neo4j.properties`

```
# Keep logical logs, helps debugging but uses more disk space, enabled for legacy reasons
# To limit space needed to store historical logs use values such as: "7 days" or "100M size"
# instead of "true"
keep_logical_logs=true

# Autoindexing

# Enable auto-indexing for nodes, default is false
node_auto_indexing=true

# The node property keys (comma separated) to be auto-indexed, if enabled
node_keys_indexable=key,name,value,email,type

# Enable auto-indexing for relationships, default is false
relationship_auto_indexing=true

# The relationship property keys to be auto-indexed, if enabled
relationship_keys_indexable=name,age,value
```

This is my SDN-Neo4j configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement                        // mode = proxy
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "graph.repository")
@ComponentScan({
    "graph.component",
    "graph.service",
    "core.service"
})
public class Neo4jConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {
    private static final String DB_PATH = "path_to.db";
    private static final String CONFIG_PATH = "path_to.properties";

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(DB_PATH)
            .loadPropertiesFromFile(CONFIG_PATH).newGraphDatabase();
    }
}
```

This is, how I attempt to delete the node

```
@NodeEntity
public class CustomEntity {
    @GraphId
    Long id;
    private String someProperty;
    ...

    public Long getId() { return this.id; }
    public CustomEntity setId(Long id) { this.id = id; return this; }
    ...
}

public interface CustomRepository extends GraphRepository<CustomEntity> {
    ...
}

@Service
public class CustomService {
    @Inject
    private CustomRepository repoCust;

    @Transactional
    public void delete(long custId) {
        this.repoCust.delete(custId);
    }
}
```

Do I have to disable the auto-indexing, when using SDN-Neo4j in order to be able to delete auto-indexed nodes, or did I miss something in my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I think disabling auto indexes is the best choice here.